# Sass , compass , @include and @extend

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have problem with Sass and this is connected with creating sprites and then reusing compiled class later.
This my styles.scss:

```
@import 'buttons/*.png';
@include all-buttons-sprites;

@import 'partial/buttons';
```

And this is buttons.scss:

```
.buttons {
  @extend .buttons-blue-button;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 242px;
  height: 45px;
  font: sky-text-med;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 24px 4px 14px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Compass not saying any errors but compile css is showing:

```
.buttons-sprite, .buttons-blue-button, .buttons, .buttons-blue-hover-button, .buttons-yellow-button, .buttons .yellow, .buttons-yellow-hover-button {
  background: url('/welcome/assets/img/buttons-s5afcdf1a60.png') no-repeat; }


.buttons-blue-button, .buttons {
  background-position: 0 0; }

.buttons {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 242px;
  height: 45px;
  font: sky-text-med;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 24px 4px 14px;
  opacity: 0; }
```

But there is missing background with should be set by @extend .buttons-blue-button;

Why this isn't happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.buttons {
    @extend .buttons-blue-button;
    ...
}
```

You are telling the .button class to **extend** the .button-blue-button class.

```
.buttons-sprite, .buttons-blue-button, .buttons, .. {
    background: url('/welcome/assets/img/buttons-s5afcdf1a60.png') no-repeat;
}

.buttons-blue-button, .buttons {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Compass is not making mistakes here, the background-image was set, the background-position was set too. Your expectations/assumptions & css-properties are Simply wrong.

Comment: Thx @mchlslzmnn . You are correct. I went thought documentation and it's working as suppose to work